# How to use torch.Tensor.permute in torchvision model

Tags: python, numpy, resnet, torchvision, permute

I am using a Resnet50 classification model from torchvision which by default accepts images as inputs. I want to make the model accept numpy files (.npy) as inputs. I understand the two have different dimensions as the numpy data is given as

```
[batch_size, depth, height, width, channels]
```

instead of

```
[batch_size, channels, depth, height, width].
```

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416819/runtimeerror-given-groups-1-weight-of-size-32-3-16-16-16-expected-input), I can use the permute function to change the order of the dimensions. However, I can't find any solution or leads on how to do this in a torchvision model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have a tensor `x` with the dimensions

```
[batch_size, depth, height, width, channels]
```

and you want to get a tensor `y` with dimensions

```
[batch_size, channels, depth, height, width]
```

The `permute()` method reorders these dimensions. You have to specify the order in which the original dimensions should be reordered to get the new ones, that is

```
y = x.permute([0, 4, 1, 2, 3])
```

If we analyze that, in the original tensor `x` the dimensions were enuemrated as

```
[batch_size, depth, height, width, channels]
 0           1      2       3      4
```

In the new tensor we therefore get

```
[batch_size, channels, depth, height, width]
 0           4         1      2       3
```

which is what we need to pass to `permute()`

Alternatively you can also just use the `einsum()` function, where you can just type the signatures which is much more intuitive.

```
y = torch.einsum('b d h w c -> b c d h w', x)
```

Comment: Thank you for the info. I tried both of your suggestions
```
tensor1 = torch.einsum('b d h w c -> b c d h w', tensor1)
```
and 

```
tensor1 = tensor1.permute([0, 4, 1, 2, 3])
```

However, I get the following error

```

RuntimeError: dimension mismatch for operand 0: equation 5 tensor 3
```
and for the second one

```
RuntimeError: number of dims don't match in permute
```

Comment: @peony Based on your initial description the proposed solutions work. Without knowing anything else about your code I cannot possibly judge what is going on. But consider posting a new question with an [MCVE], and a description of the expected and observed behaviour.

Comment: I have fixed the error by removing the b and d. Thank you