# RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 64 3 3 3, expected input[1, 4, 120, 120] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, runtime-error, vgg-net

I am using pretrained vgg16 model
import os

```
RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size 64 3 3 3, expected input[1, 4, 120, 120] to have 3 channels, but got 4 channels instead


`
```

model = torchvision.models.vgg16(pretrained =True)
`

i am unable to understand why error `your text`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [RuntimeError: Given groups=1, weight of size \[32, 3, 16, 16, 16\], expected input\[100, 16, 16, 16, 3\] to have 3 channels, but got 16 channels instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62416819/runtimeerror-given-groups-1-weight-of-size-32-3-16-16-16-expected-input)

Comment: The other related question which you added an answer to, asking for help, already has an accepted answer explaining the issue. The input should have size  `[batch_size, channels, depth, height, width]`, while you have `[1, 4, 120, 120]`, which is missing one value, and your first convolution expects the 2nd component of the input to be 3, not 4.